# Firebase not deploying from command line in mac

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I've been trying to deploy my firebase functions project for some time now and I can't seem to do it. I've followed some other question suggestions but none have worked. I've tried adding escaped colons to the predeploy:

```
"predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\""
]
```

And I've also tried renaming my spaced folder into a single word folder and it hasn't worked either. This is the error:

```
Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.8.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this is my firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\""
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

**Note**: I removed the run lint myself from the predeploy.

I can't even seem to deploy the `helloWorld` example function. When trying to serve the project I'm getting this warning:

```
Warning: You're using Node.js v9.4.0 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5
```

However, the project is actually served correctly. I've also tried uninstalling the google-cloud globally and installing it again, and the warning didn't go away.

Please help me, I've run out of ideas. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You either remove the npm --prefix or add at least one

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Or you try it with this:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```